# How to put chrome extension under task context?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, extension-methods

[image]
My extension is `Refresher`, i want to put Refresher under the task context like `AdGuard AdBlocker`.

**manifast.json**
`{
    "name": "Refresher",
    "version": "1.0",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
            "js": ["content.js"]
        }
    ],
    "browser_action": {
        /*"default_popup": "popup.html",*/
        "default_title": "Counter"
    },
    "permissions": [
      "activeTab",
      "contextMenus",
      "storage"
    ],
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
    }
}`

**content.js**

```
console.log("context started...")
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(gotMessage);

function gotMessage(message, sender, sendResponse) {
    console.log("Clicked received : "+message);
    //const cnt = document.getElementById("root").getElementsByTagName("rect").length;
    const cnt = document.getElementById("component-c332").getElementsByTagName("span").length;
    alert("Count is: "+cnt);
}
```

I want to do so because i am getting `Error in event handler: TypeError: Cannot read property 'getElementsByTagName' of null` this error while executing `document.getElementById("component-c332").getElementsByTagName("span").length` code using `Refresher` extension but when i am execute this code in console if the `javaScritp` context is in top then it's shows same error message but when i am set it to `task` then it's execute successfully.

Please help me with that. Thank you.

Comment: Add `"match_about_blank": true, "all_frames": true` to the content script declaration.

Comment: `"content_scripts": [
  {
   "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
   "js": ["content.js"],
   "match_about_blank": true,
   "all_frames": true
  }
 ],`  still not working

Comment: See i have also added 'content.js'

Comment: After editing you need to reload the extension on `chrome://extensions` page and the web page tab.

Comment: yes i did, but not working

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? You don't see your extension under `task`?

Comment: My extension is goes under `task` but is't shows same error

Comment: Your question was "How to put chrome extension under task context?" so it is working. The error is another question. You'll probably need to rework your extension. Each matching frame like `task` gets its own instance of the content script so apparently you're sending the message to the wrong content script.

Comment: Yes you have answered my question but it's shows same error. Thank you
and you can post your comment as a answer so that i can mark

Comment: @wOxxOm thank you soooooooo much ... I did it.

Comment: Then it's better if you add the answer.